# Android game "Curiosity" - how to...?

Tags: coding-style

There is a game on the android market called "Curiosity".

For those who do not know it, it's about a gigantic cube composed of many (hundreds of thousands) smaller cubes. By tapping on a cube, it gets removed.

When all the cubes are removed the game finishes.

The thing is, that the game is fully online, instant. All players together remove the cubes.

How has the author achieved this? Or actually, how can this be achieved in the most performant way (out of curiosity)? What I thought so far is that the server side *could* be using redis as a database to store the cubes data (position, etc.) and uses a combination of node.js+socket.io to emit the data of the destroyed cubes.

But what about zooming in, and getting all the cubes in a particular area? We are talking about a really HUGE ammount of data.

Also, in what way might the cubes be stored in the DB? It seemed a really simple project at first sight but it might be harder than it looks.

Here is an image of said cube; the green "areas" are the smaller cubes that need to be tapped on http://www.yourlocalguardian.co.uk/resources/images/2219589/?type=articleLandscape

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to send for each cube is a boolean value: Cube's there or cube's not there. Then at every update you only send the cubes that have changed state. It's a bit comparable to minecraft in that way. It's probably a basic socket, and i don't think it's stored at all, it's just running from RAM, probably a big 3d array.

It sounds easier than it is probably.

Comment: the thing is when you are zooming in, the application clearly seems to *download* some data, it means it gets the data when you zoom in. is it also true that each cube only has a true/false state? what about its coordinates?

Comment: I've never played the game, but i think it would be unnessecary for a cube that either exists or doesnt exist to have any other state. It might be divided in chunks, google maps like.

Comment: look at the screenshot: clearly each cube musth ave a position, otherwise how can the game know where they are located?

Comment: I played the game for a while, i think the cubes are stored either as a boolean in 6 twodimensional arrays, then colored by an image that's sent to the client, or they're stored as rgb values. The cube doesn't need a position, since the position is defined by it's location in the array.